# Push notification in angular 8

Tags: push-notification, angular8

Can anybody please help me to send push notification from one server to another using angular 8.. I have tried with firebase and angular 8..

```
export class NotificationMiddlewareService {
  messaging= firebase.messaging()
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afauth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
      (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
    )
  }
  private updateToken(token) {
    this.afauth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (!user) return;
      const data = { [user.uid]: token }
      this.db.object('fcmTokens/').update(data)
    })

  }

        recieveMessage() {
    this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      console.log("Message recieved.", payload);
      this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    });
  }
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @Hack06 i am able to send but only through post man .. i want to send through browser

Comment: @Hack06 In postman i am getting success but in browser i am not getting any pop up for push notification

Comment: maybe your browser is blocking pop-ups?

Comment: @Hack06 no in console i am getting.